# Installing Diablo 2 on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10, games

I am new to Ubuntu

I am trying to install the game Diablo 2.

I have followed all pointers I can find on installing on Ubuntu and I cant get it to work.

I have tried using furiusISO and GmountISO, Gmount asks for a password, when I put it in it does nothing. Furius says the image is not compatible. The `.bin` image mounts but does nothing and the `.cue` image is where i get the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You should try with wine (http://www.winehq.org/) - I'm playing Starcraft I and Warcraft III with this

You can install it from ubuntu software center.

Good luck :)